# Functions o1 .. o3 never called despite best efforts

Tags: haskell

```
module Main(main) where 

import Text.Printf

data RxEvent a =
    Value a
    | Error String
    | Done
    deriving (Show,Eq)

notify :: (Monad m, Foldable t, Num a1) => t (RxEvent a -> t1) -> RxEvent a -> m a1
notify subs ev =
    return $ Prelude.foldl (\ c s -> seq (s ev) (c+1) ) 0 subs

o name ev = do
    putStrLn name
    print ev
    return 0

o1 = o "o1:"
o2 = o "o2:"
o3 = o "o3:"

main = do
    nNotified <- notify [o1,o2,o3] (Value 42) :: IO Int
    printf "%d subscribers notified\n" nNotified
    return ()
```

It appears, the `seq` fails on me in the above code snippet. The `foldl` function visits all 3 members of the list and yet, no output is visible from functions `o1 o2 o3`. What did I do wrong this time? :)

Run within ghci with `:main` produces only "3 subscribers notified" but no output from the functions it was supposed to notify.

Comment: Try `notify subs ev = do { forM_ subs $ \s -> s ev; return (length subs) }`.

Comment: @melpomene Not compiling, unfortunately: ``Main.hs:14:41: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `m b0' with actual type `t1'
      `t1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          notify :: forall (m :: * -> *) (t :: * -> *) a1 a t1.
                    (Monad m, Foldable t, Num a1) =>
                    t (RxEvent a -> t1) -> RxEvent a -> m a1
        at Main.hs:13:11 .. ``

Comment: 4 hours after posting the question still nothing but a down vote and an explanatory answer, yet no solution. I would assume this is an easy question for experienced haskell users. Hence, I cannot see, why no one has mercy on me and helps me out with this. Is there some magical mystical fairy buried inside my question? Some implications which make it so hard?

Comment: My code works if you remove your type signature.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep using a fold: `notify subs ev = foldM (\c s -> s ev >> return (c+1)) 0 subs`

Comment: @melpomene Thank you so much - this is very much compatible with the way my non-monadic brain works ;) I still ponder about the change of the signature of ``notify`` but I think the way it looks now is okay for me.

Answer (score 4):

`seq` ensures that `IO` actions are evaluated, but not executed. For instance

```
print (seq (print 45) 12)
```

prints "12", not "45 12". The `print 45` part is evaluated so to to produce an `IO ()` value, which however is never executed.

To run an IO action, you have to use `>>=`, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Can you show how that looks inside the lambda of the foldl call?

Answer (score 1):

I had been aware that the invocation of the target functions should be in a monadic context. So, remembering the cryptically meaningful `_` functions and the functions ending in an `M` I saw now and then, I tried in ghci stuff like `:t foldlM` and `:t foldlM_` but of course they were not in scope because they are within `Control.Monad` package. A package I had not referenced...

Grace to the comments to my question, the working version of my code snippet looks like this:

```
module Main(main) where 

import Text.Printf
import Control.Monad

data RxEvent a =
    Value a
    | Error String
    | Done
    deriving (Show,Eq)

notify :: (Foldable t, Num b, Monad m) => t (RxEvent t1 -> m a) -> RxEvent t1 -> m b
notify subs ev = foldM (\ c s -> s ev >> return (c+1)) 0 subs

o name ev = do
    putStrLn name
    print ev
    return 0

o1 = o "o1:"
o2 = o "o2:"
o3 = o "o3:"

main = do
    nNotified <- notify [o1,o2,o3] (Value 42) :: IO Int
    printf "%d subscribers notified\n" nNotified
    return ()
```

Lesson learned: For someone trying to learn Haskell alone in an empirical manner without spending hours to learn what a random number of packages hold, getting stuck on such quite easy things is to be expected.

What I still don't quite understand is, why the contents of Control.Monad is in an extra package and not part of Prelude, since without those functions, it is quite impossible to get anything simple going...

Here, finally the hoped for output:

```
o1:
Value 42
o2:
Value 42
o3:
Value 42
3 subscribers notified
```

Comment: `foldM` isn't magic: I think in `Control.Monad` it's implemented as a recursive function but you can also implement it with `foldr` (`foldl` also kind of works but not for infinite lists)

Comment: Specifically: `foldM f b l = foldr (\a n o -> f o a >>= n) return l b` works fine